# C# record calls ToString in the base record instead of the one in the derived record

Tags: c#, record, tostring, derived-class, base-class

I have the following two records:

```
internal record Token
{
    private string content;

    public string Content
    {
        get => content;
        init => content = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Content));
    }

    public int Position { get; init; }

    public Token(string content, int position)
    {
        Content = content ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(content));
        Position = position;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Content;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Token token)
    {
        return token.Content;
    }
}

internal record CommaToken : Token
{
    public CommaToken(int position) : base(",", position)
    {
    }
}
```

and when I do:

```
CommaToken comma = new(0);
Console.WriteLine(comma);
```

it just outputs this:

```
,
```

According to the docs, a record should have a compiler-synthesized ToString method unless another method with the same signature is defined. In my case, `CommaToken` doesn't have a ToString method defined, so it should use its own synthesized ToString instead of the one in `Token`. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the specification *should* state: "If the record is derived from object, the record includes a synthesized method equivalent to a method declared as follows"

Comment: It stands to reason that a ',' is printed. The CommaToken calls the base with a ',' and fills its content. You return the content in the ToString() so a ',' is returned and printed. EDIT: Not the ToString() is called but the public static implicit operator string(Token token) which does the same as ToString().

Comment: @PaulSinnema But a cast operator shouldn't get inherited, so why does it gets called if I'm using a `CommaToken` instance? EDIT: If I do `Console.WriteLine((object)comma);` it prints the expected result of `CommaToken { Content = ,, Position = 0 }`

Comment: I tried to print a line in that conversion operator and it got printed along with the single comma, which means the conversion operator was indeed called.

Comment: My bad. It seems that operators do get inherited. It's just that they are not virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `Console.WriteLine` also accepts a string, so the compiler decided to use the `public static implicit operator string(Token token)` to cast `CommaToken` into a string, which caused the problem.
I then learned that a conversion operator should be marked as explicit if the conversion will discard information of some type. In my case, casting a `Token` to a `string` is throwing away some information, so the conversion operator should be marked as explicit.